# geometry of colorbars in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, geometry

Plotting a figure with a colorbar, like for example the [ellipse collection](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_collection.html) of the matplotlib gallery, I'm trying to understand the geometry of the figure. If I add the following code in the source code (instead of `plt.show()`):

```
cc=plt.gcf().get_children()
print(cc[1].get_geometry())
print(cc[2].get_geometry())
```

I get

```
(1, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
```

I understand the first one - 1 row, two columns, plot first (and presumably the second is the colorbar), but I don't understand the second one, which I would expect to be (1,2,2). What do these values correspond to?

Edit: It seems that the elements in cc do not have the same axes,which would explain the discrepancies. Somehow, I'm still confused with the geometries that are reported.

Comment: My output is different; I get `(1,1,1)` and the second `print` statement gives an exception, `AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'get_geometry'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is when you call `colorbar`, `use_gridspec` defaults to `True` which then makes a call to `matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes_gridspec` which then creates a 1 by 2 grid to hold the plot and cbar axes then then cbar axis itself is actually a 3 by 1 grid that has its aspect ratio adjusted

the key line in `matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes_gridspec` which makes this happen is

```
gs2 = gs_from_sp_spec(3, 1, subplot_spec=gs[1], hspace=0.,
                      height_ratios=wh_ratios)
```

because `wh_ratios == [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]` by default so the other two subplots above and below are 0 times the size of the middle plot.

I've put what I did to figure this out into [an IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/6228465)

Comment: I noticed that if I give the `colorbar()` function call an `ax` argument: `plt.colorbar(sth, ax=ax)`, the geometry of `ax` will be changed, e.g. ax is created `ax=fig.add_subplot(2,3,4)`, then after the colorbar plotting its geometry will be changed to "(2,1,1)" always, I think (2,1,1) is the plot itself, and (2,1,2) is the colorbar. If I create a new `ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,3,4)`, ax2's geometry is again (2,1,1). Could this be regarded as a bug?